# How can I change specific text color in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

First of all, Sorry for my English. English is not my first language.
I simply want to change specific text color in Google Spreadsheets.

Example

"▶Mike: Hey, How is going on?"

In this sentence, I want to change only "▶Mike:" this part.
I have no idea what's going on in Java and programming language.
But I really need this. please help.
Thank you

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `I have no idea what's going on in Java and programming language.`, when you want to achieve your goal using Java, how about using Sheets API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) By the way, I think that when you want to show your current script and add the tag of the language, that you want to use, to your question, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the color of a cell in Google Sheets, you can use one of the two options:

#### 1. Use Sheets API

For updating the color of the text, you will have to use the `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` method.

**Request**

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate
```

**Body**

```
{
   "requests": [{
      "repeatCell": {
         "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
               "textFormat": {
                  "bold": true,
                  "italic": true,
                  "foregroundColor": {
                     "blue": 1.0,
                     "green": 0.0,
                     "red": 0.0
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 1
         },
         "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
      }
   }]
}
```

If you want to use Java, you might benefit from taking a look at this snippet from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate#examples) and adapt it according to your task.

However, this option **does not** offer you the possibility of changing only a part of the text from the cell. For this, you should try using Apps Script.

#### 2. Use Apps Script

Since you want to change a particular number of characters from the cell, you can use the below script

```
function changeColor() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A2");
   var redColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("#ff0000")
      .build();
   var purpleColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("#871f78")
      .build();
   var richTextA1 = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText("▶Mike: Hey, How is going on?")
      .setTextStyle(0, 6, redColor)
      .setTextStyle(7, 28, purpleColor)
      .build();
   var richTextA2 = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText("red words, purple words")
      .setTextStyle(0, 10, redColor)
      .setTextStyle(11, 23, purpleColor)
      .build();
   range.setRichTextValues([
      [richTextA1],
      [richTextA2]
   ]);
}
```

The above script creates two text styles and later applies them depending on the `startOffset` and the `endOffset` parameters which essentially represent *which* characters will have one of the two text styles.

After executing the above script, this is how the cells will look like:

[image: change color]

#### Reference

- [Sheets API V4 Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate);
- [Apps Script Range Class - setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues).

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot.
But I missed something in my question.

Example:
"▶Mike: Hey, How are you? ▶Caren: I'm fine. ▶Mike: Okay, bye."

This all texts are in just one cell. and I want to change only "▶Mike", "▶Caren" This texts. plus, I have plenty of these cells to change.
Also, I'm get used to Microsoft Excel than Spreadsheet. Here is VBA what I used in Excel. I want to use this command in Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Sub WordColor()
Dim cell As Range, word As String, startIndex As Integer
word = InputBox(Prompt:="Write down the word", Title:="change color of text")
If Len(word) > 0 Then
For Each cell In Selection
startIndex = InStr(1, cell, word, vbTextCompare)
If startIndex > 0 Then
cell.Characters(startIndex, Len(word)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
cell.Characters(startIndex, Len(word)).Font.Bold = True
End If
Next cell
End If
End Sub


Thank you again

Comment: You will have to change the `startOffset` and  `endOffset` parameters from the `setTextStyle` in order to match the start and end of the name of each person. In this way their names will be colored differently. Please take a look at the `var richTextA1` - the `.setTextStyle(0, 6, redColor)` is used to color "▶Mike:" hence the 0 and 6 indices and the `setTextStyle(7, 28, purpleColor)` is used to color the rest of the text from the cell. If you have more words, you will have to adapt these indices to match the start and the end of the words that need to be of a different color.